# Bad white face after white cross in rubik's cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I have observed while making white face after white cross, if one of the white corner which is faced such that it's white face is towards the white cross, but the corner is corner is in wrong position, when I complete the white face it result in bad white face, what to do to remove the initial white corner due to which it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Replace it with another random corner. You can do it with the sequence R U R' or something similar.

Then

> Put the white corner back in place with the correct orientation

Comment: Do we have to check after putting each white cube that whether it is  in right position or not?

Comment: You have to put them in the correct orientation and position from the beginning. Or, if they are already on the white face (which is your case) you can use the method stated in my answer to place them in the correct position and orientation